# None of USB ports are working on Windows and Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, fedora

None of the USB ports work anymore on my [Acer Aspire E1-571G](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-E1-571G-Notebook.88806.0.html) laptop which is running both Windows 7 and Fedora 21. It can’t detect anything. For example flash memories, USB mouse, my Android phone which connected with USB cable. The phone is charging but Windows and Fedora can’t mount it.

I also tried the [suggestions in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/692337/167207) but nothing happens.

This is `dmesg` output in my Fedora Linux install:

```
[ 3461.467218] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 43, error -71
[ 3461.467274] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 3462.699066] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[ 3462.852139] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3463.106320] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3463.462544] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[ 3463.615674] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3463.869767] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3464.123921] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
[ 3464.277105] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3464.531199] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3464.785405] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
[ 3464.785592] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3464.986645] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3465.187638] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 48, error -71
[ 3465.340787] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[ 3465.340971] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3465.542052] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3465.742994] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 49, error -71
[ 3465.743049] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 3465.896048] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 50 using xhci_hcd
[ 3466.049259] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

**Edited:**

I found this link [How to fix "device not accepting address" error](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) . I think there should be some power issues but i don't know what i should do !

Comment: Any reason to suspect someone was messing around with your BIOS?

Comment: @JakeGould i edited .(my problem appears while i was working with my USB mouse and suddenly it was disconnected)

Comment: @ekaj no messing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem there is something wrong with my power manager and there is no way to fix it by any software.